# How to display portfolio items in grid on wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress

I've the maxx wordpress theme, and I want to display portfolio items from certain category in new page I made.

Here is my site: http://corenetos.com

How can I do that?

Comment: i allready did that. i search for hours without results.

Comment: You say you created a new page, but what is the problem you are facing? Do you need help to display the portfolio items? I think you have to be more specific.

Comment: Question is not clear